# What point will ADMM converge to ? A feasible point or a stationary point or local optima or global optima?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

In Boyd's great ADMM paper  [Section 3.2.1, ''Distributed Optimization and Statistical Learning via the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers''](https://stanford.edu/class/ee367/reading/admm_distr_stats.pdf), it says that as iteration index $k\to \infty$, when solving problem P1, ADMM iterates satisfy

- residual convergence, i.e., $r^k\to0$, where $r=Ax+Bz-c$,
- objective convergence, i.e., $f(x^k)+g(x^k)\to p^*$, where $f(x), g(x)$ are two convex functions, $p^*$ is the optimal value of the problem P1

Boyd also says that $x^k$ and $z^k$ need not converge to optimal values, that is, when ADMM converges, $x^k$ and $z^k$ may not be the optimal solution of problem P1.

This is very diffucult for me to understand this statement. When  $f(x^k)+g(x^k)\to p^*$ and $r^k\to0$, why $x^k$ and $z^k$ may not be the optimal solution?? My understanding is: (1) when $r^k\to0$,  $(x^k,z^k)$ is the feasible solution of P1; (2) when $f(x^k)+g(x^k)\to p^*$, the feasible solution $(x^k,z^k)$ is the optimal solution of P1.

Who can help me to understand the convegence of ADMM?

$$P1:\min_{x,z}f(x)+g(z)\\
s.t. Ax+Bz=c$$

Answer (score 1):

You should be a bit more careful with your notation. Then, the answer would likely be clearer to you.

> why $x^k$ and $z^k$ may not be the optimal solution.

Usually methods don't converge in finitely many iterations, so iterates won't be solutions. There is a limiting process involved. 
In particular the problem is that $x^k$ and $z^k$ might not converge to elements of your vector space.